# Setting the size of array in a struct by passing as a const to a function - Non-type template argument is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, struct

User sets `k` at running time. This number will be `constant` for the rest of the code. I want to create a function to pass and create a struct that includes an array of size k with that number. However, the compiler returns this error:

```
Non-type template argument is not a constant expression
```

Any recommendation will be appreciated.

The code is like:

```
template <int N>
struct UL {
    unsigned long ul [N];
};

void func(const int k){
    UL<k> x;  //problem is here
}

int main () {
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    func(k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler can't preallocate memory in an amount unknown at runtime.  Your best approach might be to create an array "factory" that is initialized when k is known, and then can return arrays of that size to every subsequent caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **fundamental principle** about templates is that:

> Any template argument **must be** a quantity or value that can be determined at **compile time**.

This has dramatic advantages on the runtime cost of template entities.

But in your example, `k` is **not** a compile time constant and you're using it as a template argument and so as a consequence of  the above quoted statement you get the error.

To **solve** your problem you can use a `std::vector` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct UL {
    std::vector<unsigned long> ul;
    
    //constructor
    UL(int k): ul(k) //this creates vector ul of size k
    {
        std::cout<<"size of vector set to: "<<ul.size()<<std::endl;
    }
};

void func(const int k){
    UL x(k);  //pass k as argument to constructor
}

int main () {
    int k; 
    std::cin >> k;
    
    func(k);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/kjU0iDYjD).

Answer (score 3):

Variable `k` is set at runtime, so when the code is being compiled, the compiler doesn't know what the value of `k` is. You can't do this. But if you know what your `k` value is going to be and the range of values it can be is limited, you can create your struct for each possible value of `k` and choose the matching class at runtime. Of course this is not probably what you want. You just need to be able to distinguish between what is known at compile-time and at runtime. Templated literals (I hope I used the right name) are a compile-time feature of C++.

Answer (score 2):

Templates are processed at compile-time only. You can't pass a run-time variable, like a function parameter, to a template.  For what you are trying to do, you will have to use `std::vector` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct UL {
    std::vector<unsigned long> ul;
};

void func(const int k){
    UL x;
    x.ul.resize(k);
}

int main () {
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    func(k);
    return 0;
}
```